# Balancing task distribution by performance in Apache Airflow

Tags: celery, load-balancing, airflow, dask

I would like to distribute work to my workers in Apache Airflow based on the health and current load of each worker. Something similar to [HAProxy leastconn](https://serverfault.com/a/453368/390615) is what I am after.

Is there a way for workers to report their load/health and have tasks distributed accordingly? I am fine with Dask or Celery, but most familiar with Celery

Comment: [Celery can disable pre-fetching](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefork-pool-prefetch-settings), which will cause workers to only pull work they can make use of.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dask it should do this automatically.  The Dask scheduler takes care of load balancing and node fallover.  I would expect Celery to do the same, though I'm less familiar there.

Comment: Does Dask check the health/load of the workers and balance based on that?

Comment: Yes.  Dask checks the health and occupancy of each of the workers. This information is used when making scheduling decisions.